# RegEx string for three letters and two numbers with pre- and post- spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Two quick questions:

1. What would be a RegEx string for three letters and two numbers with space before and after them (i.e. " LET 12 ")?
2. Would you happen to know any good RegEx resources/tools?

Comment: Did you want it to match the space between LET and 12?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a good resource, try this [website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and the program [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). You may even be able to figure out the answer to your question yourself using these sites.

To start you off you want something like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+[0-9]{2}$/
```

But the exact details depend on your requirements. It's probably a better idea that you learn how to use regular expressions yourself and then write the regular expression instead of just copying the answers here. The small details make a big difference. Examples:

- What is a "letter"? Just A-Z or also foreign letters? What about lower case?
- What is a "number"? Just 0-9 or also foreign numerals? Only integers? Only positive integers? Can there be leading zeros?
- Should there be a single space between the letters and numbers? Or any amount of any whitespace? Even none?
- Do you want to search for this string in a larger text? Or match a line exactly?
- etc..

The answers to these questions will change the regular expression. It would be much faster for you in the long run  to learn how to create the regular expression than to completely specify your requirements and wait for other people to reply.

> I forgot to mention that there will be a space before and after. How do I include that?

Again you need to consider the questions:

- Do you mean just one space or any amount of spaces? Possibly not always a space but only sometimes?
- Do you mean literally a space character or any whitespace characters?

My guess is:

```
/^\s+[a-zA-Z]{3}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+$/
```

Comment: I'm sorry, totally new to RegEx! Yes there will be a space before and after. I'm sorry I didn't specify

Comment: Before and after doesn't make sense! Your example string is 'LET 12'. That has one space, right in the middle! Do you mean you want to match ' LET 12 '? That has three spaces (left, middle, right). Also, you need to specify things like case-sensitivity, like Mark has said.

Comment: +1 You write and explain so clearly. You are a great resource to this site.

Answer (score 2):

`/[a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}/i` will match 3 letters followed by a whitespace character, and then 2 numbers. `[a-z]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) containing the letters a through z, and the `{3}` means that you want exactly 3 members of that class. The space character matches a literal space (alternately, you could use `\s`, which is a "shorthand" character class that matches any whitespace character). The `i` at the end is a [pattern modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) specifying that your pattern is case-insenstive.

If you want the entire string to only be that, you need to [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) it with `^` and `$`:

```
/^[a-z]{3} [0-9]{2}$/i
```

Regular expression resources:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info - great tutorial with a lot of information
- http://rexv.org/ - online regular expression tester that supports a variety of engines.

Comment: Why not `/\w{3} \d{2}/` out of interest?

Comment: I was being more verbose for clarity, but `\d` could be used in place of `[0-9]`. Note that `\w` is not equivalent to `[a-z]`, though! It's generally `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: Probably revenge for you downvoting Sudhir.

Comment: Nope, I got the downvote first and the downvote on Sudhir's answer is because `\w` is wrong. If the person who downvoted would like to tell me what's wrong I'd gladly fix it.

Comment: In which case, I have no idea. Someone not realising that /i does the case insensitivity for you? Or maybe because `\s` does not, as far as I'm aware, just match spaces but actually all whitespace including newlines etc?

Comment: To pick nits, the accepted answer uses `\s` as well ;) Ah well, it's just frustrating to get phantom downvotes without explanation.

Comment: It is indeed. I'd upvote you, but your regexp is technically incorrect :p. Not that the OP was very specific about it, but still. I'm a nit picker ;).

Comment: Lol! Nope, I don't do revenge, but +1 for teaching me case insensitivity and anchoring.

Answer (score 1):

`^([A-Za-z]{3}) ([0-9]{2})$` assuming one space between the letters/numbers, as in your example. This will capture the letters and numbers separately.

I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - it allows you to build a regex and test it with your own text.

Comment: Awesome, but I forgot to mention that there will be a space before and after. How do I include that?

Answer (score 0):

`\w{3}\s{1}\d{2}`
And I like [this site.](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html)

EDIT:`[a-zA-Z]{3}\s{1}\d{2}` - The `\w` supports numeric characters too.

Comment: -1 for {1}, which does not makes no sense, +1 for using character classes -> 0 in total

Comment: `\w` is not equivalent to `[a-zA-Z]`, but generally `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: @unbeli, Nothing wrong with {1} ... it's unnecessary for the regexp engine, but it's syntactically and semantically valid. It makes the regexp easier for beginners to understand because all three terms are parallel. @DanielV, good point.

Comment: @LarsH {1} is junk, does not make it simpler, does not make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably tell from the wide variety of answers, RegEx is a complex subject with a wide variety of opinions and preferences, and often more than one way of doing things. Here's my preferred solution.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\s*\d{2}$
```

I used `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w` because `\w` sometimes includes underscores.

The `\s*` is to allow zero or more spaces.

I try to use character classes wherever possible, which is why I went with `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

try this regularexpression

```
[^"\r\n]{3,}
```